# Minecraft: Give player score based on item equipped

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im working in a rpg map and i use scoreboards for strenght, intelect, talent, etc.
is it possible to give a player a score if the player is using a specific item? (armor equipped or item in main hand/specific hotbar slot)
example:

> Witch Helmet |
>    +3 intelect when equipped
>
> Broken Wand | +1 intelect -1 power when in main hand

i know it is possible to detect for a item in a players inventory but i don´t know how to only remove the stats once when the item is unequipped and make it multiplayer compatible.

Comment: The first duplicate parent answers how to detect wearing specific armour, the second detecting the "use" action of items. It's not really clear which of the two you want, but there you have answers to both.

Comment: none of them answers my question, what i do not know is how to increase and decrease an score value based on the item detection. i already know how to detect an item but when i visualize the command, it would not work as it should because if the command block detect the player has an item it would probably loop the "true" response to the detection and spam the score. that´s my doubt, how i do it properly?

Comment: the problem is that i want the score value "WHILE" the player has an item equipped.and i don´t know how to do it properly as the game has "if" and "unless" but no "whiles" so as soon as the item isn´t there anymore the exact same value gets removed once.

Comment: it´s easy with effects as you can loop the effect with a small duration and it works very nicely and as well works nice with the atributes as generic.health and etc. but how to do it with a score?

Comment: thank you for your answer, if possible remove the association with the other quetions because it´s not answered there.

Comment: I don't know your usecase, but you can probably just use a tag instead.